# What are the fields for Low-rank approximation and Principal component analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation

I would like to start with practical applications of:

- Principal component analysis
- Low-rank approximation matrices

the problem that I found is that with some internet researches I can't really place this 2 topics in a specific branch of the math, and this means that I can't even find good resources about this 2 arguments.

I work primarily with 3d geometry, so nothing related to applied statistics or other fields.

Comment: Principal components analysis belongs within a specific "branch": applied statistics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These topics are both closely related to the SVD in linear algebra.  Trefethen's book Numerical Linear Algebra has a good discussion of the SVD.  But I've seen PCA discussed more directly in Machine Learning textbooks.

Here's my attempt at an explanation of PCA via the SVD:

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_N \in \mathbb R^D$, and assume for simplicity that the mean $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n = 0$.

In order to reduce the dimensionality of our data, we can try to find a matrix $U = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & \cdots & u_K \end{bmatrix}$
such that each vector $x_n$ belongs (approximately) to the column space of $U$:
\begin{equation*}
x_n \approx U c_n
\end{equation*}
for some vector of coefficients $c_n \in \mathbb R^K$.  We will then be able to specify each $x_n$ (to a good approximation) using only $K$ numbers
rather than $D$ numbers.  If $K \ll D$ this may be a big savings.

In other words, if $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_N \end{bmatrix}$, we want to find a matrix $U$
such that
\begin{equation*}
X \approx U C
\end{equation*}
for some matrix of coefficients $C$.
If we choose $U$ well, then $UC$ will be a good *low rank* approximation to $X$.  (The rank of $UC$ is at most $K$.)

But we know how to find an optimal low rank approximation to $X$.  The SVD gives it to us.  That's why the SVD
can be used for compression.  Suppose that
\begin{equation*}
X = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i u_i v_i^T
\end{equation*}
is an SVD of $X$.
The first $K$ terms of this sum give us a very good approximation to $X$:
\begin{align*}
X &\approx \sum_{i=1}^K \sigma_i u_i v_i^T \\
&= U \Sigma V^T \\
&= UC.
\end{align*}
The PCA algorithm returns this matrix $U$, computed from the SVD of $X$, as output.

This matrix $U$ is optimal in the following sense:
if $\hat{U} \in \mathbb R^{D \times K}$ and $\hat{C} \in \mathbb R^{K \times N}$, then
\begin{equation*}
\| X - UC \|_F \leq \| X - \hat{U} \hat{C} \|_F.
\end{equation*}
Indeed, out of all $D \times N$ matrices of rank at most $K$, $UC$ is an optimal approximation of $X$
(with respect to either the Frobenius norm or the 2-norm).

Comment: Ok, I think that I start to grasp something out of this, and if I understand this correctly it would be easier ( and less computational intensive ) with normalized vectors ( all the vectors from the given set are normalized ), but I still don't have the formula or any practical applications of this, where do I start ? I'm also assuming that with SVD you mean "Singular value decomposition" and that this 2 topics are basically the same and they both uses linear algebra.

Comment: You might not want to accept my answer yet! Probably somebody else will give a more helpful answer about applications.  Maybe wait a day or two before accepting.

Comment: It's the only thing that I can do to express a vote on an answer :D , but you are right, but what about my previous comment ?

Comment: There's also an option to upvote without accepting, I believe. All the applications of PCA I've seen have come from machine learning.  I'll see if I can write more later, but hopefully someone who knows more about the applications than I do will answer as well.

Comment: if you have titles for books ... so I will get an idea from the table of contents at least, I can't upvote yet because of my low reputation level.

Comment: You mentioned no applied statistics, but one very good machine learning textbook that's free online is Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie et al.  That book may have a helpful discussion of PCA. (Btw, yesI did mean singular value decomposition when I wrote SVD.)